# What is sd(exec) process and why is it consuming 100% CPU time?

Tags: linux, fedora

I recently installed Fedora 16 with XFCE. Occasionally, a process named `sd(EXEC)` shows up and eats up all of my CPU time (CPU maxes out at 100%). Unfortunately, it cannot be killed even with `kill -9` (or maybe it is being killed but respawns fast) and I need to restart my computer.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Where does this process show up exactly? (And can you paste *exactly* what shows up?)